# acumatica add field to display values from database

Tags: customization, acumatica

I created a custom field UsrFOBprice in Stock Items Screen(IN202500),

I also created a new custom screen in Purchase Order. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYjnu.png)

How do I add Inventory ID lookup field and the custom field FOB price in this new screen which would display the values from the database?

(When I try to add new field on the new screen it says MasterTable does not exist in the database)

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

    namespace NewScreen
    {
      public class NewPurchaseOrder : PXGraph<NewPurchaseOrder>
      {


        public PXCancel<MasterTable> Cancel;


        public PXFilter<MasterTable> MasterView;
        public PXFilter<DetailsTable> DetailsView;

        [Serializable]
        public class MasterTable : IBqlTable
        {

        }

        [Serializable]
        public class DetailsTable : IBqlTable
        {

        }


      }
    }
```

[DAC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq5At.png)

Comment: can you include the code from your new screen? what are the views you are using in the graph?

Comment: included the new screen code. I haven't added any views to the graph explicitly

Comment: When you create a new screen, the project browser wizard will set up default data view and graph according to the template you choose. I'm guessing FormDetail/FormGrid here because it generated a Master and Detail DataView. What it does not create is the DAC themselves. In the graph code you included in the question, you'll have to replace the <MasterTable>, <DetailTable> by your own DAC. For example in Sales Order, MasterTable would be SOOrder and DetailTable could be SOLine.

Comment: Oh okay!
and How do I add Inventory ID lookup field and the custom field FOB price in this new screen which would display the values from the database?

Comment: How to find the <DetailTable>? 

For Stock Items Screen the <MasterTable> would be InventoryItem

Comment: Master/Detail relationship is conceptual, there's no enforcement of the constraint. For StockItems, Form along with first and second tab grids are bound to master table InventoryItem. Fourth tab Vendor Details is bound to POVendorInventory, that would make it a Detail DAC because there is a 1 to X relation. 1 inventory item has many POVendorInventory tied to it. You can find out which DAC is bound using the Inspect Element feature of Acumatica.

Comment: Inventory ID lookup field can be declared as:
public abstract class inventoryID : IBqlField { }

[Inventory(DisplayName = "Item ID")]
public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }

Comment: okay...Thank you!

and to add the custom field usrFOBPrice do I have to use PXSelector attribute? Because the field should display values from the database and the user can then edit it if needed?

Comment: Whether it goes to Database is decided by PXType (no database) or PXDBType (goes to database) ex: PXString vs PXDBString. I don't have enough info on what FOBPrice is, you can use standard text edit for numbers, selector is used for selecting from a grid popup window. If FOB needs currency support, it's gonna get a bit more complicated.

Comment: I am not able to create DAC for custom fields on the new screen it gives error "Could not load type 'NewScreen.POedit+InventoryItem' ". I have included the screenshot in the question.